# Integration test for decorated function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, integration-testing, python-decorators

I have a problem in writing integration test for some function that calls other function which is decorated. Suppose the following definitions:

```
# myproj.py

import logging


def catch_every_error(func):
    logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception("")
        else:
            return result

    return wrapper


@catch_every_error
def problematic_func():
    pass


def func_under_test():
    # doing something very critical here
    # ....

    problematic_func()
```

I need to write test to ensure that any exception raised inside `problematic_func` will not be propagated to `func_under_test`. For this reason, I used mocking like below:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from myproj import func_under_test


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("myproj.problematic_func")
    def test_no_exception_raises(self, mock_problematic_func):
        mock_problematic_func.side_effect = Exception("Boom")

        try:
            func_under_test()
        except Exception:
            self.fail(
                "exception in problematic function propagated to 'func_under_test'"
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Problem is that I can't pass this test. Patching `problematic_func` caused removal of decorator applied to that function and exceptions are not catched. For applying decorator manually, I tried:

```
    mock_problematic_func = catch_every_error(mock_problematic_func)
```

This also doesn't result with successful test passing. Exception is still raised when calling `func_under_test` in my test case. How should I test that any exception raised inside `problematic_func` doesn't cause failure in `func_under_test`?

**Note:** Please don't suggest writing test for `catch_every_error` decorator. I am trying to fulfill integration test for `func_under_test`.

Comment: `catch_every_error` *replaces* the original function with a wrapped function assigned to the same name. Your mock object isn't wrapped by the decorator; it replaces it completely.

Comment: @chepner I know it. but why `mock_problematic_func = catch_every_error(mock_problematic_func)` didn't work?

Comment: Because now `mock_problematic_func` isn't a `mock` object; it's a function that wraps a mock object, and so its `side_effect` attribute has no special meaning.

Comment: @chepner how would you implement desired test in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working version of the test above is like below:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import myproj


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("myproj.problematic_func")
    def test_no_exception_raises(self, mock_problematic_func):
        mock_problematic_func.side_effect = Exception("Boom")
        myproj.problematic_func = myproj.catch_every_error(mock_problematic_func)

        try:
            myproj.func_under_test()
        except Exception:
            self.fail(
                "exception in problematic function propagated to 'func_under_test'"
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Previously, I tried (with no successful result):

```
from myproj import catch_every_error

mock_problematic_func = catch_every_error(mock_problematic_func)
```

For some reason (I don't know exactly), importing function with `from` statement and decorating manually didn't work. Although importing whole module (`import myproj`) and manually decorating with resetting attribute (`myproj.problematic_func =`) worked.